# Tikz Feynman Delbruck Scattering

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, feynman, tikz-feynman

I'd like to make a Delbruck scattering diagram with Tikz-feynman but for some reason my code wont compile, its blowing up my CPU and eventually memory. Have I written something wrong, is there a better way to do this? I mostly just copied the box diagram from the documentation.

```
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to b] {
% Draw the top and bottom lines
i1 
-- [photon, edge label = \( \gamma \)] a
-- [fermion, edge label=\(e \)] b
-- [photon, edge label \( \gamma \)] f1 ,
i2 
-- [photon, edge label \( \gamma \)]  c
-- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e \)]  d
-- [photon, edge label \( \gamma \)]  f2,
% Draw the two internal fermion lines
{ [same layer] a -- [anti fermion, edge label =\(e\)] c },
{ [same layer] b -- [fermion, edge label=\( e \)] d},
};
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot three times to put `=` signs after label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
    \feynmandiagram[layered layout, horizontal=a to b] {
      % Draw the top and bottom lines
      i1 
      -- [photon, edge label = \( \gamma \)] a
      -- [fermion, edge label=\(e \)] b
      -- [photon, edge label=\( \gamma \)] f1 ,
      i2 
      -- [photon, edge label=\( \gamma \)]  c
      -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e \)]  d
      -- [photon, edge label=\( \gamma \)]  f2,
%Draw the two internal fermion lines
      { [same layer] a -- [anti fermion, edge label =\(e\)] c },
      { [same layer] b -- [fermion, edge label=\(e\)] d},
      };
\end{document}
```

[image]